# Is there a way to use meshlabserver to save a snapshot programatically?

Tags: command-line, 3d, meshlab

With the new 2016 version of Meshlab, is there a way to take a snapshot programatically using meshlabserver and the command line?

Comment: No. `meshlabserver` usage is pretty exhaustive. You can print that by adding the `--help` option in command line.

Comment: there is a plugin for meshlab called `filter_hqrender`. I've been trying to get that to work.

Comment: @TrevorHickey any luck with the `filter_hqrender`?

Answer (score 2):

no, sorry, screenshots are not available in MeshLabServer, as there is no way to programmatically set the view parameters.